# Changing AVAudioSession modes in app

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, avaudiosession

Is it possible to change the session category and options when a specific behavior is needed in app? For example setting:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&sessionError];
```

according to apple docs will not honor the silent switch.

The app records and plays audio. On audio playback, the app needs to honor the silent switch. Question is: Can I set the category like so:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:&sessionError];
```

when playback begins so that the app honors the silent switch. And if I do so, how will this affect routing? Apple Docs state:

> The session's category and mode together define how the application
>   intends to use audio. Typically, you should set the category and mode
>   before activating the session. You may also set the category or mode
>   while the session is active, but this will result in an immediate
>   route change.

Comment: Hey Chris, did you ever have any luck with this one?

Comment: I did, it apparently is possible to change category "on the fly" so to speak. I would have to pull the code again to see exactly how we implemented it, but it did work.

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to change, quoting the docs:

> Each app running in iOS has a single audio session, which in turn has
>   a single category. You can change your audio session’s category while
>   your app is running.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Audio_Session_Categories

So it is just a matter of calling the `setCategory:` method when you want the app to change mode.

For example, you start your app while allowing sound to play from other apps:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient error:nil]
    (...)
}
```

And when a user presses a play button on your UI, change to Playback mode:

```
- (void)playAudio {
    if ([AVAudioSession sharedInstance].otherAudioPlaying) {
        // you can check and play only if there is no other audio playing
        // maybe use another category, or enable mixing or duck option
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDuckOthers error:nil];
    } else {
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    }
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:nil];
}
```

If you want to resume the other app audio after your playback you can do a notification, or just close the session to have the other app audio to continue stopped:

```
- (void)stopAudio {
    if (self.otherAudioShouldResume) {
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO withOptions:AVAudioSessionSetActiveOptionNotifyOthersOnDeactivation error:nil];
    } else {
        [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:NO error:nil];
}
```

This code is an overview only, you might need to perform more functions to achieve a working example, also remember to check the return of these functions (BOOL) and log the errors for debugging.

Answer (score 0):

[Based on the Apple document, about AVAudioSession -setMode:error:](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/AVAudioSession/setMode:error:).

> **Discussion**
>
> The session's category and mode together define how the
>   application intends to use audio. Typically, you set the category and
>   mode before activating the session. You can also set the category or
>   mode while the session is active, but this results in an immediate
>   route change.

It sounds like the `setCategory:error:` and '-setMode:error:' are called before `setActive:error:` generally. But if those methods are called when the session is active, the audio route will change immediately.

In my case,

```
- (void)playAudio
{
   /// call `-setMode:error:` for playing audio
}

- (void)stopAudio
{
   /// call `-setMode:error:` back to original configuration, or set to another mode. It will result in route change immediately.
}
```